# Will leaving a Cursor open cause later commands to fail?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an app with a SQLite database in it; after opening a Cursor to get some data with a query like:

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id=42;`

is it necessary to close the cursor before running a command like this:

`UPDATE table_name SET column = datetime('now') WHERE id=42;`

that affects the rows in the open Cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be easy enough to test yourself.
The `UPDATE` statement will run, but the data in your existing Cursor will be out-dated.  The general rule is to close the Cursor when you are done with it and if you use [`Loader`s](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html) existing Cursors should refresh when the source data changes.

Comment: That makes sense. The problem is that one of my rows isn't updating properly (even when I run a command in the SQLite command line) and I'm just trying to figure out why not.

Comment: That's odd that to only fail on one row...  Have you double checked the data?

Comment: What do you mean? I ran a blanket statement `update table_name set column_name = datetime('now');` and it didn't affect this one row.

Comment: SQLite is quite reliable it shouldn't skip a row, usually it's the problem is a designer's logic fault, but you aren't using a `WHERE` clause. So after you ran your blanket `UPDATE`, a new `SELECT column_name FROM table_name` query returns a row with a different time?

Comment: For all rows except the one I was trying to affect, it worked fine. But, now, looking closer, it appears that maybe there's just a strange difference in times between some of the columns - so, it's got to be in my Java somewhere. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

No, you can open a cursor, execute some updates on the selected rows and close the cursor  afterwards (before `db.close()`). Sample:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT id, ...");
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int id = cursor.getLong ("id");

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("id", id +1000);
    values.put("name", name);

    db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, "id=" + id, null);
}
cursor.close();
```

Note: updates on selected tables will have no effect on the (values of the) opened cursor.